# Gunicorn only starting worker when some request is sent

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have configured `gunicorn` for 5 workers. However only 1 is started others are like in sleeping state. Only when I would try to login i.e. a request is sent to them they would fork/start for the first time.  Below is config.

```
$VIRT_ENV/gunicorn -c config.py utrade.wsgi:application \
                          --preload \
                          --log-level=debug \
                          --timeout=30 \
                          --access-logfile=- \
                          --access-logformat="%(r)s %(s)s" \
                          --log-file=-
```

Inside the django views file there tornado worker initilaztion code, there is some sort of dependency where I want all the tornado processes to be up before user logins. To make it clear, Let's say if I put `print('Hello')` in my django `views` file. It's not printed by a worker until a request is served.

How can I make gunicorn start all the workers and not wait for request? I tried `preload` flag but it didn't help.

**config.py**

```
bind = 'unix:/code/internal.utradesolutions.com/tanmay.garg/web/web/utrade/run/gunicorn.sock' 
workers = 5 
daemon=True
```

Comment: As per your configuration, gunicorn is launching your wsgi process, and nothing to do with tornado.  Can you explain the problem you are facing?

Comment: yes, but it seems it won't start wsgi until request is received to serve, may be to do some sort of optimization/lazy serving.What does `preload` flag do ? I want it should run application/django code once so that my tornado instances start running.

Comment: Can you post your `config.py` ?

Comment: @garg10may Did you solve your problem? Because my app takes a long time to load, if an user happens to make a request and it is the first request a worker receives, it will take a long time for that response to arrive.

Comment: @VictorVal I don't think your problem is same as mine if the response is taking long time, debug your code to find bottlenecks. For me, I did a sort of hack whereby I created a sample fake method in the view and called it externally multiple times so that all the workers are started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a process manager (like [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/)) to manage the tornado process separately from gunicorn which is running your wsgi process.

As far as `preload`, this is an optimization that loads your code before the workers start ([docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#preload-app)):

> Load application code before the worker processes are forked.
>
> By preloading an application you can save some RAM resources as well
>   as speed up server boot times. Although, if you defer application
>   loading to each worker process, you can reload your application code
>   easily by restarting workers.

Comment: it's not related to tornado, it is just causing confusion, let's say there's a print statement at the start of my django views file, I want 5 prints to be printed before serving any request. But only 1 print is there and rest of the prints are printed when I login, i.e. view file is loaded for the first time which is when a request is served by the worker.

Comment: That's because once the request is handled, there is no more need to have it handled by another worker. guincorn does not distribute the same request to multiple workers. See this link: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/faq.html#does-gunicorn-suffer-from-the-thundering-herd-problem and http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html